# How do you make a c++ program search for a string?

Tags: c++, string, search, if-statement

How do you make a c++ program search for a string?

I'm new to the programming language c++.

Is there a way so that my program will look for a string of a .txt file and do something if the program found it?

Comment: Start with step 1. Write code until it works

Comment: +1 because you are actually asking a question (not everybody does that) and -1 because you forgot the "?" :P

Comment: If you are new to C++, you should get a book. There are plenty on the market and any good one that covers the basics will also introduce i/o and strings. Otherwise, you should show some effort and search the web (e.g. there are tons of questions on SO on this topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open an ifstream to open your file then check for the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      if(line.find("the string to find") != string::npos)
      {
         //line found, do something
      }
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer...

but can you explain it more briefly because i don't understand most of it.

Comment: As other people already commented, search before you ask next time.

Comment: @HyperLord Your question is very close to "I want to build a nuclear plant but I never took physics, could you briefly explain it to me?", with the difference that you can actually make nice pictures to explain how nuclear plants work.  (They use nuclear reactors to heat up water, which propels turbines).  So, learn physics (basics of C++, basics of searching the Internet). Search Google for every line of this small program. You'll learn :)